# Cypress - Assert only one element with a text exists

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have a table and I want to ensure that values are not repeated within a column using Cypress. Currently, I am doing

```
cy.get("#myTable")
  .find(".table")
  .contains("unique_value")
  .should("exist")
```

This piece of code does check if a value in a column exists but it doesn't ensure that its the *only* entry with this value in the table. How do I check for uniqueness through Cypress?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Surprisingly, this

```
cy.get("#myTable")
  .find(".table")
  .contains("unique_value")
  .should('have.length', 1);
```

or even this

```
cy.get("#myTable")
  .find(".table td")
  .contains("unique_value")
  .should('have.length', 1);
```

will return a **false positive** - if you run it with two `unique_value` table cells it incorrectly passes.

Ref [contains - yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Yields) indicates a single value is returned.

---

The best way I found was to shift the `contains()` up into the `.find()` selector,

```
cy.get("#myTable")
  .find('.table td:contains("unique_value")')
  .should('have.length', 1)
```

---

The above tests uniqueness between cells. If you want to also test the value **within the cell**, the simplest way is to invoke the `text()` method.

```
cy.get("#myTable")
  .find('.table td:contains("unique_value")')
  .should('have.length', 1)          // ensure only one cell has value
  .invoke('text')
  .should('equal', 'unique_value')   // check the exact content of the cell
```

See the first example on this page [Assertions](https://example.cypress.io/commands/assertions)

Answer (score 1):

sorry about the previous answer, I forgot with .contains it selects sorts out 1 element from the found list. anyway, there are two ways to do this.

1st :
it'll look like,

```
  cy.get(".table") 
   .find(('td:contains("unique_value")'))
   .should('have.length', 1)
```

Note: This might be problematic if the same table cell has repetitive **unique_value**

For example: Let's say you are expecting a unique id (1234)  in a table cell, but the table looks as follows

```
<tr>
<td>1234, 1234<td>
<td>value<td>
<tr>
```

If we take this scenario, the above solution will make the test as passed even though the unique id is repeated in the same cell. If you want to validate those kinds of scenarios too, I think the best solution would be,

```
  cy.get(".table")
  .then($el => {
    expect($el[0].innerText.split('unique_value').length).to.equal(2)
  })
```

in this case, if the table does not contain **unique_value** the array length will be 1 and if it has more than 1 **unique_value** the array length will be more than 2 so, this will work with any string, paragraph, table, etc.

cheers.

Comment: Why do you propose a more complicated way to do the same thing?

Comment: it's not complicated,  As I mentioned in the answer, the first method will work fine. I was thinking about the other possible scenarios for that solution to break.
for example,  we are expecting our table to have a unique id = 1234  due to a dev issue, the table cell is like <td> 1234, 1234 </td>

This is a scenario where the test should fail. But if we use the first method it will be marked as pass as it checks the number of <td> elements. 
Didn't mean to make it complecated tho.

Comment: Ok, seems to be a valid point but should edit your answer to make clear the problem  solution #2 is solving.